# Download Parisienne font on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, apt-get

I tried to install the [Dancing Script](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Dancing+Script)  font on an Ubuntu VM through command lines. Following the instructions on [this website](https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/fonts-dancingscript) worked:

```sh
apt-get install -y fonts-dancingscript
```

---

I am now trying to install the [Parisienne](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Parisienne) font but I cannot manage to find how to do it or find the *"ubuntu name"*. I tried to guess:

```sh
apt-get install -y fonts-parisienne
```

but, I got the error:

```
Unable to locate package fonts-parisienne
```

---

What is the correct command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with the help of [@hookey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69206025/12066144):

What I did was:

```sh
wget -P /usr/share/fonts/truetype/parisienne/ https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/5c3d8ef085f3084db38936d0dcd39a567dbc1e01/ofl/parisienne/Parisienne-Regular.ttf
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all fonts exist in the Ubuntu package repository.

You can find all fonts in the repository here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=fonts-

You can download the Parisienne font files and install them manually: https://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately installing manually is not an option as it has to run in a pipeline ... Do you know how I can know whether or not a font is supported or not (I mean a better way than just looking at all the font from your link or trying random keywords)?

Comment: Not sure about knowing whether a font is in the repository or not, but in a pipeline you could `wget` the fonts directly from the [css file](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Parisienne&display=swap) that Google Fonts provides and move them to your fonts folder. It seems that Google also has them on GitHub: https://github.com/google/fonts